# For loop if statement recognizes == but not < in Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop, html-table, inequality

I'm trying to create a script that will replace certain values in my table with other values. I generated a table in HTML that works fine. I want to replace the elements in the 4th column in each of the first 3 rows with the value 1/8".

```
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
 var cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
 if (i < 3) {
  cells[3].innerHTML = '1/8"';
 }
}
```

Using the above code does nothing for my table, however using the following code replaces the 4th element with my value

```
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
 var cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
 if (i == 3) {
 cells[3].innerHTML = '1/8"';
 }
}
```

Why does == work, but < does not? Are there easy ways to print out the outputs of the for loop so i can debug easier - Im new to coding. Thanks!

Edit: Here is the HTML I'm using, along with the CSS (which is probably not necessary)

HTML5:

```
<div class="eo_product_listing_table">
<table class="tableizer-table">
<thead>
  <tr class="tableizer-firstrow">

    <th>Item #</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Operting Temp.</th>
    <th>O.D.</th>
    <th>Length</th>
    <th>Material</th>
    <th>Junction</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Order</th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
  <!--1/8-->
  <!--6-->
  <tr>
    <td>NB4-CAXL-14U-12-AAG</td>
    <td>K</td>
    <td>-270°C to 1372°C</br>–454°F to 2501°F</td>
    <td>3/8"</td>
    <td>6"</td>
    <td>316SS</td>
    <td>Grounded</td>
    <td>$51.00</td>
    <td><a href="/">Order</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NB4-CAXL-14U-12-AAU</td>
    <td>K</td>
    <td>-270°C to 1372°C</br>–454°F to 2501°F</td>
    <td>3/8"</td>
    <td>6"</td>
    <td>316SS</td>
    <td>Ungrounded</td>
    <td>$53.00</td>
    <td><a href="/">Order</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NB4-CAXL-14U-12-AAE</td>
    <td>K</td>
    <td>-270°C to 1372°C</br>–454°F to 2501°F</td>
    <td>3/8"</td>
    <td>6"</td>
    <td>316SS</td>
    <td>Exposed</td>
    <td>$51.00</td>
    <td><a href="/">Order</a></td>
  </tr>
  <!--12-->
  <tr>
    <td>NB4-CAXL-14U-12-ABG</td>
    <td>K</td>
    <td>-270°C to 1372°C</br>–454°F to 2501°F</td>
    <td>3/8"</td>
    <td>12"</td>
    <td>316SS</td>
    <td>Grounded</td>
    <td>$53.00</td>
    <td><a href="/">Order</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NB4-CAXL-14U-12-ABU</td>
    <td>K</td>
    <td>-270°C to 1372°C</br>–454°F to 2501°F</td>
    <td>3/8"</td>
    <td>12"</td>
    <td>316SS</td>
    <td>Ungrounded</td>
    <td>$55.00</td>
    <td><a href="/">Order</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NB4-CAXL-14U-12-ABE</td>
    <td>K</td>
    <td>-270°C to 1372°C</br>–454°F to 2501°F</td>
    <td>3/8"</td>
    <td>12"</td>
    <td>316SS</td>
    <td>Exposed</td>
    <td>$53.00</td>
    <td><a href="/">Order</a></td>
  </tr>
  <!--18-->
  <tr>
    <td>NB4-CAXL-14U-12-ACG</td>
    <td>K</td>
    <td>-270°C to 1372°C</br>–454°F to 2501°F</td>
    <td>1/8"</td>
    <td>18"</td>
    <td>316SS</td>
    <td>Grounded</td>
    <td>$57.00</td>
    <td><a href="/">Order</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NB4-CAXL-14U-12-ACU</td>
    <td>K</td>
    <td>-270°C to 1372°C</br>–454°F to 2501°F</td>
    <td>1/8"</td>
    <td>18"</td>
    <td>316SS</td>
    <td>Ungrounded</td>
    <td>$59.00</td>
    <td><a href="/">Order</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NB4-CAXL-14U-12-ACE</td>
    <td>K</td>
    <td>-270°C to 1372°C</br>–454°F to 2501°F</td>
    <td>1/8"</td>
    <td>18"</td>
    <td>316SS</td>
    <td>Exposed</td>
    <td>$57.00</td>
    <td><a href="/">Order</a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

CSS3

```
.eo_product_listing_table {}

.tableizer-table tr:nth-child(even) {
   background-color: #eee;
}

table.tableizer-table {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

.tableizer-table td {
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 0px solid #CCC;
  text-align: left;
  color: black;
}

.tableizer-table th {
  background-color: #104E8B;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
}

.tableizer-firstrow {
  background-color: #000;
  color: whtie;
}
```

Comment: `console.log` is your best bet for printing debugging information for you script. The console is also where you can find any unhandled errors your code is raising.

Comment: Are you sure each row has at least four `td`s? Are you getting any errors? Have you tried using the debugger?

Comment: @Luaan I believe there are 9 tds in each row unless the code isn't picking them up the way I think it is

Comment: Well, you're going through all `tr`s in the document. Could it be that you're reading an entirely different table?

Comment: @Luaan no i dont think so. It works when i say if i == 3. It just doesnt work when i switch to an inequality, i.e. i < 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use your script for ALL `<tr>` tag's, just like @Luaan said - look into your HTML file. That's mean, you must count form 1, not form 0. Then everything works fine.

```
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
 var cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
 if (i < 4) {
 cells[3].innerHTML = '1/8"';
 }
}
```

Comment: Ofc, I accepted your answer but it says i need 15 rep for my upvote to be visible. Thanks though, i do greatly appreciate the help

Comment: @MatthewSirkin now it's OK :)

Answer (score 0):

For the first three iterations of your loop (`i < 3`) you are just setting the same cell's `innerHTML` to `'1/8"'` again and again and again.

Maybe you'd meant to do:

```
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  var cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
  if (i < 3) {
    cells[i].innerHTML = '1/8"';
  }
}
```

Comment: By making it cells[i] it's changing which td in the row to change. I always want to changed the 4th element in each row. Hence why I thought it would be cells[3]. But I want to change the 4th element in a bunch of different rows. My thinking was that it would run through the for loop checking the if statement and for each run through where i < 3, it would replace the 4th element in that row with the desired value... if that makes sense

Comment: @MatthewSirkin you want the first three rows to all have `1/8"` in their fourth cell?

Comment: yes, that's correct each of the first 3 rows would have their 3/8" value replaced with 1/8". I actually want to do this with a bunch of nested for loops but if I can get this to work I'm pretty sure I can do the rest myself.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, now that you've posted your HTML, the error is in plain sight :) The first `tr` you find contains no `td`s whatsoever, so you get an unhandled error and the function breaks.

You need to only look for rows in the `tbody`,  excluding any that might be in `theader` or `tfooter`. It's also generally a good idea to make only iterate through rows of a particular table, rather than all rows in the whole document. You could even give the specific `tbody` an id and access it directly, avoiding all those issues.

Comment: That makes sense, so in my HTML I would say:

Comment: <tbody id="tablebody"> and then I would just use getElementsById?

Comment: @MatthewSirkin There's a few different ways of doing that. If you don't need to support old browsers, `document.querySelectorAll("#tableBody tr")` will probably work best. If you can't do that, `document.getElementsById("tableBody").getElementsByTagName("tr")` will work fine.